# Console.Error.WriteLine does not work when invoke from another console application

Tags: .net, console-application

I have a console application that is developed using .Net 6.0. Following code works when I run this application directly from the console.

```
string l_ErrMsg = "Error !";
Console.Error.WriteLine(l_ErrMsg); // works
Console.WriteLine(l_ErrMsg); // works
```

But when I invoke the same console application from another console application, '**Console.Error.WriteLine(l_ErrMsg)**' does not work.

```
string l_ErrMsg = "Error !";
Console.Error.WriteLine(l_ErrMsg); // Does not work
Console.WriteLine(l_ErrMsg); // works
```

Both are console applications and developed using .Net 6.0. Following is the code to invoke the applicaiton:

```
using (var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
{

    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "\\Some\\Path";
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "MyApp.exe";

    string l_errorOut = null;

    process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
                                { l_errorOut += e.Data; });

    string l_CmdLine = string.Format("--Arg1={0}", argument1);

    process.StartInfo.Arguments = l_CmdLine;

    lbProcessStarted = process.Start();



}
```

Comment: `WorkingDirectory = "\\Some\\Path"` <-- This is not a valid path btw: the backslashes are escaped, so this isn't a UNC path.

Comment: You need to call `BeginErrorReadLine()` to initiate reading via `ErrorDataReceived` - **or** use the `StreamReader` returned from `StandardError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what @Dai Suggested. Here is the final code:

```
using (var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
{

    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.Combine(BinaryPath, "..\\SomePath");
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "MyApp.exe";   
    

    process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
                            {        
                                // This will write to console          
                                WriteLine(e.Data);
                            });

    string l_CmdLine = string.Format("--Arg1={0}", argument1);

    process.StartInfo.Arguments = l_CmdLine;

    lbProcessStarted = process.Start();

    process.BeginErrorReadLine();

    process.WaitForExit();

    if (process != null)
    {
      process.Close();
    }

}
```